# Matlab: How to change the scaling of the legend on a wind rose plot

Tags: matlab

This may be a very simple problem but I would greatly appreciate your help. I have created a direction/intensity plot using the wind_rose function in Matlab, however, I would like to change the scaling of the legend. The plot currently produces a legend that has 12 colors that go up in 10 cm blocks, for example blue = 0-0.1, light blue = 0.1-0.2, green = 0.2-0.3 etc. I would like there to be far less colors and the scaling to be more like blue = 0-0.5, light blue = 0.5-1.0 etc. This is the code I use to plot the wind rose:

`h = wind_rose(M,D,'dtype','meteo','n',12,'lablegend','Hm0 (metres)','ci', 0:10:60,'quad',[4])`

Am I able to add a simple code that will scale the legend how I want it to be?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
'di', 0:0.5:3
```

Very simple really oops. I am now looking to remove white boxes that appear around text on the figure, any ideas?